# What are these "badges" called?

Tags: gui-design, terminology, page-layout, empty, page

They're usually used to tell the user that a list is empty, or a resource could not be found, or that a resource may be unavailable.

SoundCloud has one here for tracks without any comments:

[image]

Or if there are no tracks on a profile:

[image]

I would love to incorporate these into my design, as they help fill the empty space there would be when there is no content.

Comment: I would just call those "illustrations" or "icons."

Comment: I typically call them placeholders: [Facebook content placeholders](http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You described an empty state, or zero-data state. Examples of empty states are a list with no elements (no comments on the track, like in your image or no tracks), a search query with no results.

> [The most basic empty state displays a non-interactive image and a text tagline.](https://material.google.com/patterns/empty-states.html#)

You can read more here:

- [Empty states | Google](https://material.google.com/patterns/empty-states.html)
- [Designing For The Empty State | Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/09/designing-for-the-empty-states/)
- [UX Best Practices: Designing the Overlooked Empty States |
  Invision](http://blog.invisionapp.com/why-empty-states-deserve-more-design-time/)

Comment: Please elaborate instead of just posting links, what if people in the future want to refer to this question, and the links are all broken?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen In fact, was just a question and I think I answer. He needed to know what term describe what is in the design. I just thought I help with the documentation.